# benefits of a blade vs. mallet putter

Tags: equipment, golf

What are the main differences between a blade vs. mallet putters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mallet putters have a bigger clubhead (while maintaining a similar weight as the blade putter). Also, the weight in mallet putters is located away from the clubface, resulting in its center of gravity to be toward the back of the putter.

The benefits of a mallet putter are:

- Forgiveness (better stability when putts are off-center wrt the clubface).
- Promotes a straight back-straight through putting stroke.

The benefits of a blade putter are:

- Simple design, not too much theatrics with this type of club. WYSIWYG.
- Promotes a inside-outside-inside/through putting stroke.
- Improved feel compared to a mallet putter.

Personally, I play with a blade putter. I didn't mind a mallet putter, but I would sometimes ground my club on longer putts due to the weights. I do not have this problem with blade putters. However, this is more choice with respect to comfort level and feel than anything else.

Sources:

- http://golftips.golfsmith.com/difference-between-blade-mallet-golf-putters-20031.html
- http://golf-info-guide.com/putters/blade-vs-mallet-putter-heads/